# In iOS, is it possible to use Apple SDKs to remap a key for a hardware keyboard globally?

Tags: ios, keyboard, custom-keyboard

Given an external hardware keyboard is in use such as the Apple Magic Keyboard for iPad, is it somehow possible either by installing a custom keyboard or other technique to remap one or more keys "globally" ( meaning in any app or on the home screen )?  There's the `UIKey` object provided by Apple, however that seems app specific.

Simply put, I'd like to perform actions such as swapping the "p" key with semicolon.  Open to any / all creative ideas.  I can remap keys via software keyboards such as xKeyboard successfully via installed custom keyboards in settings, however I need a solution that can remap keys when using the Apple Magic Keyboard specifically.

References:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst/handling_key_presses_made_on_a_physical_keyboard